# Angular2 router does not work without node js

Tags: angular

I have angular2 app which uses router it works fine with nodejs cause i added

```
<base href="/" />
```

in my index page but when i deployed app on my server in subfolder it gives error(i fixed it with making static paths in html) but still it cant load router pages

no any error given by browser but just no route link opened

Comment: If you don't think it's a duplicate please add a comment. You need to configure the server to support HTML5 pushState or switch to `HashLocationStrategy`.

Comment: configuring the server is not possible i am on shared server :( looking into HashLocationStrategy

Comment: now the error is 
cannot find http://localhost/app/main.js in angular.polyfill.js :(

Comment: That seems to be an issue with your project configuration.